# Grails UrlMappings problem

Tags: rest, grails, service

I'm implementing a rest service in grails so I created a controller:

```
class LoaderController {

  def index = { }

  def save = {

    String input = params.er3f
    render 'OK'

  }
}
```

And added the following in UrlMappings:

```
"/loader/$id?" (controller:loader) {
   action = [GET:"save"]
}
```

When I run http://localhost:8080/MyApp/loader?er3f=12345678, I get a 404 and description The requested resource (/MyApp/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/loader/index.jsp) is not available.

But when I run http://localhost:8080/MyApp/loader/save?er3f=12345678 works OK.

What's wrong with my UrlMappings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you're not using the mapping you defined. You specify an `id` parameter but pass `er3f` and don't use / syntax but put it in the querystring with ? - calling http://localhost:8080/MyApp/loader/12345678 would use the syntax.

But you're also mixing two different approaches in the mapping itself, so it's not firing. You can use a Map and specify the action and controller in parens, or use a Closure and specify them there, but you can't mix them.

And finally, you've specified an `id` parameter but are looking for an `er3f` parameter in the controller, so that will always be null.

This is the mapping you want:

```
"/loader/$er3f?" {
   action = [GET:"save"]
   controller = 'loader'
}
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know that we cannot mix declaration of actions/controllers in parens together with Closure

Comment: You could mix controller and action definitions actually: Example: 

`"/validate/"(controller:"addressVerification"){action=[GET:"validate"]}`